# Is possible use the operators "$ne" and "$elemMatch" in same query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find all documents that `tipo=CD` and canciones does not contains subdocuments that has `title=Pajaritos` and `cancion=2`

This is what i like to achieve in `canciones` field:

```
not (title=Pajaritos and cancion=2)
```

I have the following collection:

```js
{ 
    "tipo": "CD",
    "Artista":"Los piratas",
    "Titulo": "Recuerdos",
    "canciones": [
        {
            "cancion":1,
            "titulo":"Adios mi barco",
            "longitud": "3:20"
         },
         {
            "cancion":2,
            "titulo":"Pajaritos",
            "longitud": "4:15"
         }
     ]
},
{ 
    "tipo": "CD",
    "Artista":"Los piratas",
    "Titulo": "Recuerdos",
    "canciones": [
        {
            "cancion":1,
            "titulo":"Adios mi barco",
            "longitud": "3:20"
        },
        {
            "cancion":3,
            "titulo":"Pajaritos",
            "longitud": "4:15" 
        }
    ]
},

{ 
    "tipo": "CD",
    "Artista":"Los piratas",
    "Titulo": "Recuerdos",
    "canciones": [
        {
            "cancion":1,
            "titulo":"Adios mi barco",
            "longitud": "3:20"
        },
        {
            "cancion":3,
            "titulo":"Pajaritos",
            "longitud": "4:15" 
        },
        {
            "cancion":4,
            "titulo":"Pajaritos4",
            "longitud": "44:15" 
        }
 }
```

My query

```
db.media.find({"tipo" : "CD" ,"canciones" : { "$ne" : {"$elemMatch" :  {"titulo" : "Pajaritos", "cancion" : 2}}}})
```

My undesired results

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550f0a1c009ed3a1c9bbcdc1"), "tipo" : "CD", "Artista" : "Los piratas", "Titulo" : "Recuerdos", "canciones" : [ { "cancion" : 1, "titulo" : "Adios mi barco", "longitud" : "3:20" }, { "cancion" : 2, "titulo" : "Pajaritos", "longitud" : "4:15" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550f0a1c009ed3a1c9bbcdc2"), "tipo" : "CD", "Artista" : "Los piratas", "Titulo" : "Recuerdos", "canciones" : [ { "cancion" : 1, "titulo" : "Adios mi barco", "longitud" : "3:20" }, { "cancion" : 3, "titulo" : "Pajaritos", "longitud" : "4:15" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550f0a1c009ed3a1c9bbcdc3"), "tipo" : "CD", "Artista" : "Los piratas", "Titulo" : "Recuerdos", "canciones" : [ { "cancion" : 1, "titulo" : "Adios mi barco", "longitud" : "3:20" }, { "cancion" : 3, "titulo" : "Pajaritos", "longitud" : "4:15" }, { "cancion" : 4, "titulo" : "Pajaritos4", "longitud" : "44:15" } ] }
```

As you can see, the results contains `"titulo" : "Pajaritos"` which is trying to avoid.

Trying with `$not` operator instead of `$ne`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550f173fc357b7a4e7a46e10"), "tipo" : "CD", "Artista" : "Los piratas", "Titulo" : "Recuerdos", "canciones" : [ { "cancion" : 1, "titulo" : "Adios mi barco", "longitud" : "3:20" }, { "cancion" : 3, "titulo" : "Pajaritos", "longitud" : "4:15" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("550f173fc357b7a4e7a46e11"), "tipo" : "CD", "Artista" : "Los piratas", "Titulo" : "Recuerdos", "canciones" : [ { "cancion" : 1, "titulo" : "Adios mi barco", "longitud" : "3:20" }, { "cancion" : 3, "titulo" : "Pajaritos", "longitud" : "4:15" }, { "cancion" : 4, "titulo" : "Pajaritos4", "longitud" : "44:15" } ] }
```

Comment: Do you want only subdocuments in `canciones` that matches the given criteria or document?

Comment: @Michael I want the document.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In order to get the expected results, I would use the [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator instead of the [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator. The [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator would pretty match negate [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and give you the expected results. Your query shall therefore be:

```
db.media.find({
    "tipo": "CD",
    "canciones": {
        "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "titulo": "Pajaritos",
                "cancion": 2
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I've already try with $not operator and confuse me even more, because is still showing "Pajaritos" but one result less. I updated the question.

Comment: Oh I think I understand a bit more what you trying to achieve. You do not want the results to contain documents with  "canciones.titullo" = "Pajaritos" OR documents with "cancans.cancion" = 2. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I'm trying "not (canciones.titullo=Pajaritos and canciones.cancion=2)"

Comment: In that case, it appears from the sample data you provided that 2 documents should be returned.

Comment: Do you want documents where (in the same array element) `titullo` is not `"Parajitos"` AND `cancion` is not 2, or documents where `titullo` is not 2 OR `cancion` is not 2. By the DeMorgan laws, not (`titullo=Pajaritos` and `cancion=2`) is equivalent to the latter - "not both" is equivalent to "not one or not the other". It is not equivalent to "not one and not the other".